# TeamCity artifact paths combine folders

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I need to create zip archive artifact which contains two folders. I know how to create one folder archive:

```
Folder1 => myartifact.zip
```

But how can I tell TeamCity to add Folder2 to same archive?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The same target_archive name can be used multiple times, for example:

```
*/.html => report.zip
*/.css => report.zip!/css/
```

See also: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Configuring+General+Settings#ConfiguringGeneralSettings-artifactPaths